# Refer to Backbone view's child element

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

Having just rendered a view like so:

```
render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    return this;
},
```

How can I refer to one of the template's child elements and apply a jQuery function to it?

Comment: You should see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17172746/why-using-the-this-selector-method-syntax-with-backbone/17173755#17173755

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Backbone Views expose [a dollar **`$`** function](http://backbonejs.org/#View-dollar) that will use jQuery under the covers, but within the context of the view itself.

```
this.$('.child_element_of_my_view_template')
```

This will work even if the view is detached (`$el` not in DOM) but will obiouvsly only work by the time the element you want to select exists within the view (appended to `$el`).

This means that you can safely use it after the first line of your `render` function.

Comment: aah yes, this is what I had tried but it seems to reference elements from other views too, using this.$('foo')[0] works but I haven't figured out exactly what is going on. Could be something to do with Google Charts API

Comment: @amiawizard.. Check what `this.$el` refers to . Looks like it is pointing to a element higher up in the `DOM` tree

Answer (score 1):

this.$el is now a regular jQuery element so you can call .children on it:

```
this.$el.children()
```

Use whatever jQuery selector you need, or .eq(index) after it